# Query Parse Array Data down into local array, and add to TableView (Swift)

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform

Hi first i'd like to say (Thank you) in advance. I apologize as I feel like a huge idiot.

So I've successfully pulled an array of objectId's from parse and added it to a local array called [teamArray] See below:

```
func getTeamData() {
    var query = PFUser.query()
    query?.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: displayedTeamId)
          query!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            println("Successfully retrieved \(self.displayedTeamId)")
            // Do something with the found objects
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    var team:AnyObject? = object["team"]
                    self.teamArray.addObjectsFromArray(team as! [PFObject])
        --> successful print here: println(" I have a full \(self.teamArray)")
                    // code to download an image
                    let imageFile = object["teamImage"] as! PFFile

                    imageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {

                        (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if error != nil {
                            println(error)
                        } else {

                            if let data = imageData {
                                self.showTeamImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
        }
    }
}
```

The team array is like so:

```
var teamArray:NSMutableArray = []
```

So, my goal is to take each object in the array, and add it into into the tableView cells.

I have no idea how to do this. I'll re-iterate.

1. I want to pull down the parse array which is an array of objectId's (as Strings)
2. I want to extract each ObjectId within the [teamArray], and add that object into it's own cell.
3. Pull the data out of that object.

   - profile photo
   - name
   - location
   - age
   - gender

Now how do I approach this???

Answer (score 0):

This example that I am about to show you is for **iOS 9 with the new parse SDK**.

You want to display a lot of information in your TableViewCell, so create a model **for example struct**  which contains all those informations.

```
struct PersonalInfo
{
    var profilePhoto:UIImage!
    var name:String!
    var location:CLLocationCoordinate2D!
    var age:Int!
    var gender:String!
}
```

- Put this structure outside of the ViewController class

Then instead of having an array of  `NSMutableArray` array just create an `var arrayOfData = [PersonalInfo]()`

- Your query will now look like:

  ```
  func getTeamData()
  {
  var query = PFUser.query()
  query?.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: displayedTeamId)
  query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects:[PFObject]?, error :NSError?) -> Void in
      if error == nil
      {
          if let objects = objects
          {
              for one in objects
              {

                  let imageToRetreive = one["imageFromParse"] as! PFFile
                  imageToRetreive.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (data :NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                      if error == nil
                      {
                          if let data = data
                          {
                            let finalImage = UIImage(data: data)
                              let name = one["username"] as! String
                              let gender = one["gender"]  as! String
                              let age = one["age"] as! Int
                              let location = one["Location"] as! PFGeoPoint

                              var Info = PersonalInfo()  

                              Info.name = name
                              Info.gender = gender
                              Info.age = age
                              Info.profilePhoto = finalImage
                              Info.location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.latitude, location.longitude)

                              self.arrayOfData.append(Info)
                              // <--- then reload the tableview

                          }

                      }
                  })
              }
          }
      }
    })
   }
  ```

  - Then in you **cellForRowAtIndexPath** method you will have something like:
        var data = arrayOfData[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel.text = data.name
        // <---- access everything from the array using the **.** method from data

Comment: So I appreciate the feedback. But i'm a little afraid to change anything as i'm a new developer using swift.

Comment: The object["team"] is an array of ObjectId's in parse related to a PFUser. Each PFUser will have an array of their own once created. What i'm trying to do is take down each of these objectId's and get the data from each of them.

Answer (score 0):

The question needs a little more clarification. First of all, is object["team"] returning an array? or is it representing one single object?
Another option going off on the answer above is to use PFSubclassing to represent your results as parse objects
It could look something like this:

```
class Team: PFObject, PFSubclassing {
    @NSManaged var profilePhoto: PFFile?
    @NSManaged var name: String

    // The name of your class in parse
    static func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "Team"
      }

    override class func initialize() {
        struct Static {
          static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
          self.registerSubclass()
        }
      }
}
```

This way you can perform all of the PFObject operations on your objects
Eg.

```
let team = Team()
team.name = "Team name here"

let imageNamed = UIImage(named: "image.jpg")
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageNamed, 1)
let imageFile = PFFile(data: imageData)
team.profileImage = imageFile
team.saveInBackground()
```

Comment: i'll be able to get back to you about this tomorrow, I won't have immediate access, but will try a few things. Thank you!